# How to insert multiple row on table2 from multiple inserted row of table1 in SQLServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

Example 
Table1

```
(pk,col1,col2) values
(1,ABC,DEF)
(2,GHI,XYZ)
```

Now after 1 & 2 pk gets inserted in table1
If PK is 1 then
Table2 should have

```
(pk,col1,col2 FK_pk_table1)
(1,abcgroup,1),
(2,abcgroup,1),
```

and PK is 2 then
Table2 should have

```
(3,xyzgroup,2),
(4,xyzgroup,2)
```

Comment: what is the table schema, data types , any identity columns etc???

Comment: Table1 
(col1 int pk, col2 varchar, col3 varchar)
Table2
(col1 int pk, col2varchar, col3 int FK_talbe1_pk)

Comment: why you need multiple records in child table for a single parent table record? Seems like you need a after insert trigger which need to be fired twice after each insert in parent table